# C++ std::map compare method

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

I ran into error with the following code

```
struct MapKey {
    std::string x;
    std::string y;
}

std::map<MapKey, int> m;

if (m.find(key) != m.end()) {
    ......
}
```

I receive an error says,

```
no match for "operator<" in '__x < __y'
```

I believe the problem is that MapKey needs to have a compare method, I am wondering how can I implement one for Mapkey. For example,

```
struct MapKey {
    bool operator<(const MapKey &key) const {
        ... what shall I put here? ...
    }
    std::string x;
    std::string y;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define this after `MapKey`'s definition (as a free function, not a member function) and you're set:

```
bool operator <(MapKey const& lhs, MapKey const& rhs)
{
    return lhs.x < rhs.x || lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y < rhs.y;
}
```

Make sure to define the operator as `inline` if the definition is in a header file, otherwise you risk linker errors.

Comment: Thank your for your reply. Is there any particular reason why define the operator < as a free function, but not as a member function of MapKey? Thanks.

Comment: @2607 : It's technically possible to, but generally making operators that don't _have_ to be member functions (e.g. assignment operators) member functions is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

Any function （which can take const arguments） that induces a [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering) is OK. Also remember you don't need an operator==, but two keys a and b are considered equivalent if and only if !(a < b) && !(b < a).

Comment: Here's another excellent article on what strict weak ordering means/is: [Order I Say!](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2010/02/order-i-say/)